How can i avoid hiding the keyboard when the onPress event(Pressable) is triggered?
My React Native app has a search screen(Page A) that goes back to the previous page when hiding the keyboard; Clicking on the search results will take you to the search results page(Page B). The problem is that clicking on a search result hides the keyboard, making the KeyboardDidHide event activated. The KeyboardDidHide event will cause a return to the previous page, causing the jump to page B to never be executed.
Is there a way to prevent hiding the keyboard when I press on another pressable component so that the KeyboardDidHide event doesn't fire
Here are the Code:
const Search: FC = () => {
  // state, refs
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const _inputText = useDeferredValue(inputText);
  const [searchResult] = useSearchItem(_inputText);
  // KeyboardHide Detector
  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardHideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        navigation.goBack();
      },
    );
    return () => {
      keyboardHideSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
          <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            {searchResult.map(result => (
              <Fragment key={result.id}>
                <List.ItemContent
                  onPress={e => {
                    navigation.navigate('Detail', {
                      itemDetail: result,
                    });
                  }}>
                  <Text>{result.name}</Text>
                </List.ItemContent>
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <Shadow>
          <View>
            <SearchInput autoFocus value={inputText} onChange={setInputText} />
          </View>
        </Shadow>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
};


Make use of the Keyboard.dismiss() to explicitly dismiss the keyboard when needed.
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

const Search: FC = () => {
  // state, refs
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const _inputText = useDeferredValue(inputText);
  const [searchResult] = useSearchItem(_inputText);

  const handleSearchResultPress = (result) => {
    Keyboard.dismiss(); // Dismiss the keyboard explicitly
    navigation.navigate('Detail', {
      gatheringItem: result,
    });
  };

  // KeyboardHide Detector
  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardHideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        navigation.goBack();
      },
    );
    return () => {
      keyboardHideSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {searchResult.map(result => (
            <Fragment key={result.id}>
              <List.ItemContent
                icon={
                  <Icon
                    as={ExternalLinkIcon}
                    w={px2DpX(16)}
                    h={px2DpX(16)}
                  />
                }
                onPress={() => handleSearchResultPress(result)}>
                <Text>{result.name}</Text>
              </List.ItemContent>
              <View key={`divider-${result.id}`} />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <Shadow
          style={styles.panelWrapper}
          startColor={colorMode === 'light' ? '#00000020' : '#00000000'}>
          <View>
            <SearchInput autoFocus value={inputText} onChange={setInputText} />
          </View>
        </Shadow>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}


Thank you ! I solved the problem through the use of the way you just recommend and used 'keyboardShouldPersistTaps=always' in combination, solved the problem
